# Radio button pseudo-element positioning problems in a container with a percentage width

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have the following radio buttons set up with a percentage-width container:
[image]

The circle in the middle has to be centred, of course.

I have found this to be quite tricky with pseudo-element positioning.

Depending on the browser's width, the circle is not always horizontally centred. Here is a gif of the radio buttons, while resizing the window:
[image]

Is it possible to keep this circle centred while maintaining a percentage-width container?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-section gender">
  <div class="label-col">
    <label>Gender</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />
    <label for="male"><span>Male</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
    <label for="female"><span>Female</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (compiled from SCSS):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.gender {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gender .form-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}
.gender input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
}
.gender .form-section label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: gray;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.gender .form-section label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.gender input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
  content: "•";
  color: blue;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 17px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}
.gender input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXxvZW

Comment: Looks good for me: http://i.imgur.com/kCeCUyu.png. What's the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar The problem is that the blue circle inside the radio button moves around

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zejzqbwn/

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes Thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: your welcome @alanbuchanan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `translate` to position the inner dot to center the label and changed the label styling to add outer border

```css
.gender {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gender .form-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}
.gender input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
}
.gender .form-section label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
  color: gray;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 16px;
}
.gender .form-section label span {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0.7
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
.gender .form-section label:before {
  content: "";
}
.gender input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  width: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 8px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}
.gender input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section gender">
  <div class="label-col">
    <label>Gender</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />
    <label for="male"><span>Male</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
    <label for="female"><span>Female</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used both `::after` and `::before` to construct this. Kindly check thoroughly and see if it works.

```css
input[type="radio"] {display: none;}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="radio"] + label::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: #999;
  top: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section gender">
  <div class="label-col">
    <label>Gender</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />
    <label for="male"><span>Male</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-section">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
    <label for="female"><span>Female</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

**JSBin: http://jsbin.com/bapepahequ**

Comment: The same issue of horizontal alignment remains, Version 51.0.2704.36 beta (64-bit). Try resizing your browser, you may see what I mean

Comment: @alanbuchanan Using 50.

Comment: Same thing happens on Safari 9.1 and Firefox 41. I don't think this is a  browser-specific problem

Comment: @alanbuchanan Can we use two things: `::after` and `::before` so that both are positioned perfectly, instead of using a text content? What do you think?